# Multiple onprogress event handlers from xhr in loop

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently trying to build an ajax image uploader and I have it working except for one important part.

For each separate file I upload I would like to update a progress bar for the file. Currently it only updates the last files progress bar.

```
       $("#upload-btn").click(function() {
            console.log("Click");

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append("file", files[i]);
                fd.append("__RequestVerificationToken", $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val());

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', "@Url.Action("AjaxUpload")", true);

                var filename = files[i].name;

                xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                        console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');

                        var progressbar = $('a[data-name="' + files[i].name + '"]').siblings(".progress").find(".progress-bar");
                        progressbar.css("width", percentComplete + "%");
                    }
                };

                xhr.onload = function () {
                    console.log(this.status);
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        var resp = JSON.parse(this.response);
                        console.log('Server got:', resp);
                    };
                };

                xhr.send(fd);
            }
        });
```

As you may have guessed from the code, I'm pretty terrible at javascript... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope your file name in the progress callback, currently it will only use the last value of `i`. Replace where you set your `onprogress` handler with this code.

```
(function(filename) {
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
           var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
           console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');

           var progressbar = $('a[data-name="' + filename + '"]').siblings(".progress").find(".progress-bar");
           progressbar.css("width", percentComplete + "%");
        }
    };
})(files[i].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Set the additional parameters of xhr.upload

```
// Set custom properties
xhr.upload.targetFileName = fileName;
```

and then access it in progress handler like this

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
   
   // Access custom properties. 
   var fileName = e.target.targetFileName;
}
```

More details here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/xhr-progress-and-richer-file-uploading-feedback/ view-source:http://mozilla.pettay.fi/xhr_upload/xhr_file_upload_demo_with_speed.html